# UI-Test on ShareExtension

Tags: xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

Is there a way to use Xcodes automated UI-Testing features to automate a test in a Share-Extension. We do have a few tests in our app running, but we were not able to break out of our app and use e.g. the Photos.app to share some files with our app.

So: is there a way to use UI-Tests to leave the app, share some files from another app and return to the app afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to testing extensions here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/36212000/840262